# Visual C++ 2010 - fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, visual-c++-2010-express

this is a program :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "Enter a number";
int i;
cin >> i;
try {
    if( i == 0 ) throw 0;
    if( i == 2 ) throw "error";
} catch( int i ) {
    cout << "can't divide by 0";
 }
   catch( ... ) {
       cout << "catching other exceptions";
   }
}
```

On compiling (Microsoft visual C++ 2010 express on Windows 7), I get the error which says:

> fatal error LNK1169: one or more
>   multiply defined symbols found

Comment: Try removing code until the error disappears-- that will give you a clue.

Comment: I don't see the error using Visual Studio C++ 2010 on XP.

Comment: I like your first line of this question! Anyway, it compiles fine for me using g++ on linux.

Comment: This code compiles and works fine in dev c++ ver4.9.9.2

Comment: perhaps you have another int main somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Actually there is no error in this code**.

Number of source files could be the problem.
Try this code as a new project in the same compiler or try deleting the files from the `source files` option in the left side of Text Area (i.e where you are writing your code)

This should compile then.

Comment: Why would the number of source files be a problem? /GenuinelyCurious

Comment: it compiles the whole project and finds multiple main methods.

Comment: Gotcha. I thought you were saying the number of source files could be the problem. As though there were a limit to the number of files that can be compiled. I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I think that I found the most plausible explanation for the problem as you know we usually assign main as an integer (int main) in our .cpp file and sometimes we may write more than one .cpp file in the same project with the same (int main () ).so for the program that means we have accidentally repeated the same function twice in the same project folder .What we have to do is this just write one .cpp file with (int main) while the other .cpp files in the same project write them with (int submain) and see what gona happen.

Answer (score 2):

try to change your `int main()` to `int submain()`.

Comment: Please don't answer old threads that have accepted answers given years ago. Use your energy to help in current questions instead

Answer (score -4):

I suspect your error come from this line :

```
catch(int i)
```

You've already got a variable named like that in this range. Also, you should catch exceptions, not integer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the i is in a different scope.